# How to make a copy of Pandas DataFrame in the correct way

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [{"a": 5}, {"a": 8}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Output:

```
    col1    col2
0   1       {'a': 5}
1   2       {'a': 8}
```

And I have the following code piece (from a bigger program):

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    n_df = (r.to_frame().T).copy()
    n_df['col2'][i]["a"] = n_df['col2'][i]["a"] - 1
    print(n_df)
    
df
```

Output:

```
  col1      col2
0    1      {'a': 4}
  col1      col2
1    2      {'a': 7}

    col1    col2
0   1       {'a': 4}
1   2       {'a': 7}
```

At the end, I actually expect **df** remain unchanged because I do use the **.copy()** function when creating **n_df**.

Where am I making a mistake here? How should the code above look like so that manipulating **n_df** will not change the **df**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply use [`DataFrame.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) here. See the note at the bottom of the page:

> Note that when copying an object containing Python objects, a deep copy will copy the data, but will not do so recursively. Updating a nested data object will be reflected in the deep copy.

A possible (ugly?) solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import copy

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [{"a": 5}, {"a": 8}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    n_df = pd.DataFrame([copy.deepcopy(r.to_dict())], index=[i])
    n_df['col2'][i]["a"] = n_df['col2'][i]["a"] - 1
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   col1      col2
0     1  {'a': 5}
1     2  {'a': 8}
```

Comment: So, what should I do if using the copy() function is not the option?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is working. Why do you think this solution is ugly? Does it have performance drawbacks? Do you think it is a bit cumbersome to read & understand..? Or another thing..?

Comment: Maybe you should extract the whole column (and get a list of dict) then deepcopy this list (instead of each single dict) so process it outside of Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

By the [definition](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

> When deep=True (default), a new object will be created with a copy of
> the calling object’s data and indices. Modifications to the data or
> indices of the copy will not be reflected in the original object (see
> notes below).
>
> Note that when copying an object containing Python objects, a deep
> copy will copy the data, but will not do so recursively. Updating a
> nested data object will be reflected in the deep copy.

Comment: So, what should I do if using the copy() function is not the option?